# Undefined symbol after source ros

Tags: ros, python3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I create my own library with setuptools. When I run the command in terminal :

```
python3.8
```

Then I import my library, it works properly.

But if before starting python3.8, I run **source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.sh**

I get an error when I import the python library   :

```
import vmpbcvt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/vmpbcvt-1.0-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg/vmpbcvt.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZN19VisionModuleManager15SetCurrentImageB5cxx11ERN2cv3MatEb
```

Can you explain me how it could be possible ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/418106/undefined--symbol-after-source-ros/) by [xavier12358](https://answers.ros.org/users/28095/xavier12358/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2023-08-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you for all you answer.

I finally find the problem. In fact previously I add a library in my catkin workspace build folder, the one I now build externally.

When I source the devel/setup.sh, the library used was not the library located in /us/lib/ ... but the older library in catkin_ws.

Thank you Mike Scheutzow and bluegiraffe-sc for your time.

---

Originally posted by [xavier12358](https://answers.ros.org/users/28095/xavier12358/) with karma: 62 on 2023-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1